# force http.globalAgent.keepAlive = true

Tags: node.js

I have this node CLI tool that consumes all my network's NAT (network address translation) address ports whenever it runs because the node tool creates a connection per outbound http request. The tool doesn't finish the job because the NAT gateway blocks the tool from opening any more outbound ports after the node tool exceeds the limit.

I could set `http.globalAgent.keepAlive`, but the problem is that this node CLI tool `execs` to other modules so I would have to set `http.globalAgent.keepAlive` in all those sub modules as well. Is there a way I can force `http.globalAgent.keepAlive` everywhere without changing code in every `sub-execed` node tool?

Comment: Can you not make your networking script exit in an error state by using `process.exit(1)` when it fails to obtain a port, so that the parent script that called the exec will know its exec failed and can take appropriate measures?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the main issue is that if I'm making thousands of `http` request to an API it is very inefficient to open a TCP connection per request. This is not a server, but a client. Hope the edits clarify that!

Comment: If you're making thousands of API calls, you should probably write an API proxy and have _that_ use a single (or small pool of) connection(s) that the rest of your code talks to?

Comment: That's a good approach as well, but that proxy still has to expend resources opening the excessive number of connections from the client app. The proxy's CPU/Memory is certainly far more abundant than the NAT's number of available addresses. I think the proxy would also need to be HTTP capable as well right? It couldn't just be a TCP proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `node` command supports a `--require` flag which preloads a module (or several modules) before executing file passed to `node`.

Because of the `require` cache, if a module imports the `http` module and sets `http.globalAgent.keepAlive = true` then any other module that imports `http` will be importing `http` from the `require` cache with `http.globalAgent.keepAlive = true`.

Therefore, the key is to override the system's `node` command to `--require` a module that sets `http.globalAgent.keepAlive = true`. Whenever the CLI tool `execs node` the script runs instead and imports the override module first. The require cache will be pre-populated with `http` and the desired settings for that `node` process.

A script like the following will pass through any arguments to node and load the overriding module any time a call to `node` occurs.

```bash
#! /bin/sh

exec node_bin --require /path/to/module "$@"
```

You'll also need to move the original `node` binary to something like `node_bin` and insert the above script as the new `"node"` binary.

Comment: Pretty sure module caching does not apply to newly spawned node processes though? As far as I understand it, each node process has its own module cache.

Comment: Yes, you have to override the `node` executable to force anyone calling `node` to call a passthrough script instead. Therefore any new process is unwittingly requiring the module. Not great for most systems, but excellent in a docker container.

Comment: It's a HUGE hack :D